# rails: active model serializer looking for wrong serializer

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

When I call the the create method i get a nameError.

```
Failure/Error: post :create, { user: { email: 'charles@example.com',
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant API::V1::UsersController::UserV1Serializer
```

why is it adding that UsersController module to the class it is looking for? In my sessions controller I use the same exact render line and it doesn't complain. what is going on?

### app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb

```
class API::V1::UsersController < API::V1::BaseController
    ...
    ...
    def create
        user = User.new(user_params)
        if user.save
          sign_in :user, user, store: false
        end
        render json: user, serializer: UserV1Serializer, root: 'user'
      end
```

### app/serializers/api/v1/user_v1_serializer.rb

```
class API::V1::UserV1Serializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email

  def attributes
    hash = super
    if scope == object
      hash[:token] = object.authentication_token
    end
    hash
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of specifying `UserV1Serializer`, you need to specify the full namespaced class name `API::V1::UserV1Serializer`.

If you just specify the `UserV1Serializer`, its looking for the serializer class within current controller `API::V1::UsersController::UserV1Serializer` which is why you get an error as

`uninitialized constant API::V1::UsersController::UserV1Serializer`.

Use this instead:

```
render json: user, serializer: API::V1::UserV1Serializer, root: 'user'
```